# Skype Chat History: Adding person to current chat sees previous history?

Tags: skype, privacy, history

I had a private conversation with someone over IM and then added a third person to the group for a call. Is the third person able to see the history of my previous conversation? Or they only can see history from the point they joined the conversation?

I've searched everywhere for info on this and can't confirm, I'm very worried!

Comment: very good question, +1!

Comment: +1 for good question. I would like to know also

Answer (score 4):

Default Skype settings are to NOT SHOW any messages before joining group chat.
But you can override that with `/set options +HISTORY_DISCLOSED`, which would make skype show chat history up to 400 messages or 2 weeks back (whichever is less).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, (s)he will be able to do so.

Source: Personal experience.

Comment: Oops, that's bad. Good thing I got them to erase their chat history. Not sure if that will work but crossing my fingers.
Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: You're welcome @midorichan